# Getting the most info from .NET Cache

Tags: c#-4.0, caching

I'm playing around with the retrieval of the most information I can regarding the use of .NET Caching.

With the `Cache` object we can retrieve 3 parameters

- `Count`
- `EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit`
- `EffectivePrivateBytesLimit`

But how about all the rest?

Where can I get information such as "available memory in server", "used cache memory", and so on...

There was a old project in [ASP Allience](http://aspalliance.com/) called **Cache Manager**, but it's no longer available and all I could find was an image of it, where it does display exactly this:

[image]

I was looking at the docs and reading about the new .NET 4 entries in the `System.Runtime.Cache` like the [`CacheMemoryLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.cachememorylimit.aspx) and [PhysicalMemoryLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.physicalmemorylimit.aspx) but I can't find real examples on how do I use it...

Does anyone have a wrapper for Cache Info around? or any idea how to use this new methods available?

my current Cache Implementation is:

```
public class InMemoryCache : ICacheService
{
    private int minutes = 15;

    public T Get<T>(string cacheID, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        T item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheID) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
                cacheID,
                item,
                null,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes),
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Stats()
    {
        var cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
        var r = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        r.Add("Count", cache.Count.ToString());
        r.Add("EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit", cache.EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit.ToString());
        r.Add("EffectivePrivateBytesLimit", cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit.ToString());

        return r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz_7hukyejQ

This is based on a 100% managed custom memory manager that stroes cached items in byte[] segments that are like 256 mb in size. This allows to store 100s of millions of objects without slowing anything down as GC does not see the "objects" as they reside in byte[].

The video shows how one can see cache in action and see how many objects,pages,priorities etc...

Here is the code:

https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/tree/master/Source/NFX/ApplicationModel/Pile

Namely the main interface of cache:

https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/blob/master/Source/NFX/ApplicationModel/Pile/ICache.cs

You can have named tables, age-based or absolute timestamp expiration with memory limits and entry priorities